# Changing an external data variable vuejs

Tags: vue.js, global-variables

Using vuejs. Is it possible to change the value some data variable from an external file? For example

file1.js

```
export default{
   data: function(){
      somevar: false
        }
      }
```

file2.js

```
import otherfile from "./file1.js"
otherfile.data().somevar = true
```

This didn't work. The somevar value wasn't changed in file2.js . How can I change the value in file2.js and if not possible what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: share live demo which not works for you ?

Comment: You probably needed a `prop` rather than `data`.

Answer (score 1):

it would likely be easier to set up file1.js so that somevar is a computed property that relies on the import of file2.

Using vuejs. Is it possible to change the value some data variable from an external file? For example

file1.js

```
import importedVar from './file2.js'

export default{
   computed: {
      somevar: function() {
          if (importedVar) {
            return importedVar
          } else {
            return false
          }
        } 
      }
```

file2.js

```
export default true
```

Comment: will somevar change when importedVar is changed?

Comment: [yes, it should](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)